# How to call a local variable from another function c

Tags: c, function, variables, call, local

I am new to programming. I would like to call from functions(first, second, third the variables in function "enter" and in function "math" accordingly).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void math (void);
void first (void);
void second (void);
void third (void);
void enter(void);
void scan(void);


int main() 
{

 first();  //function
 second(); //function
 third();  //function
 enter();  //function
 printf("\n\n Would you like to edit? (Y/N)\n\n");
 scan();   //function
 return(0);
}
```

Here is the user input:

```
void first (void){
float a;
printf("Enter First number: ");
scanf("%f",&a);
 }

 void second (void){
 float b;
 printf("Enter Second number: ");
 scanf("%f",&b);
  }

  void third (void){
  float c;
  printf("Enter Third number: ");
  scanf("%f", &c );
  }
```

How can I call the variables from the user input to the function below?

```
  void enter(){
  float a,b,c;
  printf("you have entered a: %f, b: %f, c:%f", a,b,c);
     }
```

This is the loop in case the user would like to edit or continue with the initial  input numbers.

```
    void scan(void){
    int ch;
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if (ch==1){
        main();

        }else{
        math();
        }
        }
```

Here I would also like to call the input variables from function (first, second third) in order to perform some math calculations.

```
        void math (void){
           float a,b,c;
           float x,y,z;
           x=a+b+c;
           y= powf(x,2);
           z=sqrt(y);

           printf("Final Result of Addition is: %f \n Final Result of 
           Multiplication is: %f \n Final Result of squareroot  is:%f\n 
           ",x,y,z);
                          }
```

Comment: Local variables are just that: Local. If you need to share them between methods you need to return them from the function and the calling function is responsible for capturing those return values and storing them somewhere.

Comment: local variables cease to exist when the functions they're in return.. recommend reading up on variable scope: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=9caVWo_eCceK0wKW-qGgCw&q=c+variable+scope&oq=c+variable+scope&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l8.892.3064.0.3262.16.12.0.0.0.0.325.1016.0j4j1j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.6.1013...0i131k1.0.QkODFhbFB8s

Comment: @tadman It's not meaningless in C.  An empty argument list means the function takes an unspecified number of arguments, while an unnamed `void` argument means the function takes no arguments.  In C++ they're equivalent.

Comment: @dbush Is this still the case in C99? I've only seen that used in really old code.

Comment: You are complicating the problem by repeating similar but useless functions. Get **one** function working first, and I suggest you adopt a development style from this approach: don't write a wall of code without proving each step. The smaller the step you test and stretch, the better and easier it will be, even if it seems like too much work. You wrote several functions – and now they all need re-writing.

Comment: @tadman For function prototypes, yes it is the case in C99 and C11.

Comment: Guys thanks for contributing. I really appreciate it !! I solved it by making them global variables. But how can I do it by storing them in another function and get them as arguments ? Any reference...

Comment: @KlaydPro You can't.  Read up on passing parameters to and returning values from functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best if functions don't depend or modify data external to them. It's not always possible but it is better if they can be defined with that goal in mind.

In your case, the functions `first`, `second`, and `third` are doing essentially the same thing. It will be better to use just one function and give it a more appropriate name, such as `read_float` and change the return type so that the value input by the user is returned to the calling function.

Declare it as:

```
float read_float(char const* prompt);
```

Then, you can use it as:

```
float a = read_float("Enter the first number:");
float b = read_float("Enter the second number:");
float c = read_float("Enter the third number:");
```

etc.

The function `enter` does not correctly convey what it is doing. It should be renamed to something more appropriate, such as `display_input_values`. It can accept the values input by the user as its arguments.

Declare it as:

```
void display_input_values(float a, float b, float c);
```

and use it as:

```
float a = read_float("Enter the first number:");
float b = read_float("Enter the second number:");
float c = read_float("Enter the third number:");
display_input_values(a, b, c);
```

The `scan` function does not convey its meaning clearly either. You could divide `scan` to two functions -- one that returns you the option of whether to continue with the next inputs or to call a function that computes something with the user input.

You can get the option from the user by using a function named `read_int` function as:

```
int option = read_int("Enter 1 for next round of inputs and 2 to compute with current input:");
```

and use that returned value as:

```
if ( option == 2 )
{
   // Do the computations
}
```

You also need another option to exit the program. The call to get the option needs to be:

```
char const* prompt = "Enter 1 for next round of inputs.\n"
                     "Enter 2 to compute with current input.\n"
                     "Enter 3 to exit program.\n";
int option = read_int(prompt);
```

Always add code to check whether `scanf` succeeded before proceeding to use the data that you were expecting to read into.

---

Here's an updated version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float read_float(char const* prompt);
int read_int(char const* prompt);
void display_input_values(float a, float b, float c);
void math(float a, float b, float c);

int main() 
{
   while ( 1 )
   {
      float a = read_float("Enter first number: ");
      float b = read_float("Enter second number: ");
      float c = read_float("Enter third number: ");

      display_input_values(a, b, c);


      char const* prompt = "Enter 1 for next round of inputs.\n"
                           "Enter 2 to compute with current input.\n"
                           "Enter 3 to exit program.\n";
      int option = read_int(prompt);
      if ( option == 3 )
      {
         break;
      }

      else if ( option == 2 )
      {
         math(a, b, c);
      }
   }
}


float read_float(char const* prompt)
{
   float num;
   printf("%s", prompt);

   // For flushing the output of printf before scanf.
   fflush(stdout);

   if (scanf("%f", &num ) != 1)
   {
      print("Unable to read number. Exiting.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   return num;
}

int read_int(char const* prompt)
{
   int num;
   printf("%s", prompt);

   // For flushing the output of printf before scanf.
   fflush(stdout);

   if (scanf("%d", &num ) != 1)
   {
      print("Unable to read number. Exiting.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   return num;
}

void display_input_values(float a, float b, float c)
{
  printf("You have entered a: %f, b: %f, c:%f\n", a, b, c);
}

void math(float a, float b, float c)
{
   // Do whatever makes sense to you.
}
```

Comment: As a number of terminals do not flush `stdout` before `scanf()`, adding `fflush(stdout);` between `printf("%s", prompt);` and `if (scanf(...` insures the prompt is seen first.

Comment: Hats off !!! Thanks  a lot !  it was very clear. I am just beginning the journey of programming. So I am trying to acquire as much as possible by excellent  programmers as you !

Comment: @KlaydPro, you're welcome. I am glad I was able to contribute to your learning.

Answer (score 0):

For example declare `float a,b,c;` in your Main and change your functions to return a float
`float first() { ... }`
Then write`a = first();`

Answer (score -1):

Local variables (as name suggests) are local and can't keep their values after function ends. You have two options:

1. Make functions first, second and third return their numbers and another functions get them as arguments.
2. Make a,b,c global variables.

The second one is much easier, but it's so called bad programming style.

Comment: A third option would be to use malloc and pass the variables to the functions.

Comment: Ok I solved it with the 2nd way.
But how can I do it with 1st way by storing them in another function and get them as arguments ?

Comment: @KlaydPro Have the functions return the values they read, then pass those values to the other functions that need them.  Also, don't recursively call `main` but use a loop instead.

Comment: I did sth like this :

 void first (){
printf("Enter First number: ");
scanf("%f", &a );
return a;
}

Having: float a; as a global variable.

Now How can I read the returned value  to "enter" function?

Comment: Then you have a syntax error. `void` before function means that it doesn't return anything. You have to choose one option: either returning value or global variables.

Comment: Can’t you also pass the variables by reference?